# how to detect the repeated values in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have these data:
m= {'a' 'b' 'a' 'v'}

how to make an if statement that if I have a repeated values in the row, I should omit this row 
I have this code but it is not a direct code... I want something more profisional (one line function without for loop !!)

```
for j=1:length(m)
    if isequal(m{1,j},m{1,j+1})
        disp('error');
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the unique command. It can also find repeated rows from a matrix http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#btb0_85

Comment: Your example data is a vector and unique works with it (R2012b). Can you give an example where it fails?